# Advice on gluster volume backups

Tags: backup, volume, glusterfs

So, I have a three node gluster sharing a single volume.  There are two clients connecting to that volume.  I'm installing my backup agent on all the nodes and clients.  I would like to try to reduce duplication of backups not only for space but for network overhead.  This is not mission critical data.  Would it be sufficient to just back up the brick on the first gluster node and maybe one of the two clients or just the brick?  My backup software would be just doing a standard file system backup.  I know this is a subjective question but I would just like to get some feedback.

Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 1):

Backing up brick alone is not a good idea.

To keep it simple, you can run your rsync tool(or any backup tool) from client machine to wherever your destination is.

OR You can make use of gluster geo-replication to do the backup. Note here, the backup destination must be a gluster volume.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I use a filesystem agent from a commercial backup software.  I guess I'll just do two backups, one of one of the bricks and one from one of the clients...